# mate-system-monitor won't show in Application menus, plus errors when launched in terminal

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files, gtk

I installed mate-system-monitor on my elementary OS Loki install via AppCenter, but I couldn't find it in the Applications menu. I searched for it, with no luck. So I uninstalled it, and installed it again in my terminal.

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install mate-system-monitor
```

It installed propperly, so I searched in my applications menu but still couldn't find it. So I tried launching it from terminal.

```
$ mate-system-monitor
```

It worked partly as it opened up the monitor and the monitor worked fine. But the terminal showed errors.

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap"
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap"
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap"
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

** (mate-system-monitor:6768): WARNING **: SELinux was found but is not enabled.
```

I fixed the first 4 lines by following [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66356/gdk-gtk-warnings-and-errors-from-the-command-line), but how can I fix the last 2 lines and also be able to find the monitor in my Applications menu?
(I tried uninstalling and installing again, but it didn't work.)

Comment: oh, so I think Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module" is another bug  And it doesn't change how the application runs. So now this is my  question: why doesn't mate-system-monitor show up in the applications menu? and what does this error mean?:** (mate-system-monitor:6768): WARNING **: SELinux was found but is not enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to realize that when you choose to install ElementaryOS, you choose Wingpanel+Plank+Gala and NOT Mate, not even Unity

when you read inside the file

```
/usr/share/applications/mate-system-monitor.desktop
```

you can find the following line

```
OnlyShowIn=MATE;
```

pretty clear

you can try removing that line but that app is part of the Mate environment not Elementary, you should go to their website to ask them how to run it outside Mate

https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-utils/issues

---

PS: the message

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
```

is "normal"

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the app menu does not find it because it does not install any appdata in metainfo.  Gnome system monitor provides this and does appear in the app menu.